# How to get first and last element <li>?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to get first and last element in `<li>`:

```
<script>
  function editMediaInfo(mediaID){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]
    alert(x);
  }
</script>
```

```php
<?php
  $x = 1;
  echo "<ol>";

  while($x <= 5){
    echo "<li id={$x}> item {$x} </li>";
?>
<button onclick="editMediaInfo('<?php echo $x; ?>')">Click</button>
<?php
    $x++;
  }

  echo "</ol>";
?>
```

When I click the button, I’d like to get the first and the last element in `<li>`. How can I do that?

Comment: To show your `<li>`s as the literal text "`<li>`", surround them with backticks ``(`)``. Also, are you trying to get the first/last `<li>` element, or the first/last element inside the list item (e.g. the `<span>` in `<li><span>Hello!</span></li>`)?

Comment: Maybe it becomes more clear if you show the html bit ;)

Comment: i would like to get the last and the first id <li id={$x}>

Comment: Click on any button (you have 5) will show just last and first li? Also, better give unique identifier to your list (if there are more of them on page).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way with `lastChild` property

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    var lastchild = x.lastChild;
    alert(lastchild);
```

Comment: alert says [object Text]

Comment: Look for the `property` you need